# MVC Site versus Virtual Application Routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7, tfs

We use TFS to deploy our applications to multiple environments (Dev, QA, Prod). Simple enough, our Dev and QA environments have URLS like dev.domain/APPLICATION and qa.domain/APPLICATION. So we have a single site with each application as a virtual application.

However in production, they want each application to be its own site, such as APPLICATION.domain.com... Grrr! In Visual Studio, the application's properties is configured to be in a "Virtual Path". I"m not sure how I should go about this issue. The appliation contains code such as: `<a href='/APPLICATION/File/Download?id=<#= PkFileId #>'><#= Name #></a>` which causes problems in production since its not in a virtual application.

I could make a site called application.domain.com with an empty directory. Then add a Virtual Application, but then I would have to put a redirect in the root of the site to go to the virtual application. Or perhaps I can somehow configure the application? Not sure what my options are... Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The appliation contains code such as:
>
> `<a href='/APPLICATION/File/Download?id=<#= PkFileId #>'><#= Name #></a>`

ASP.NET MVC applications should not contain code like that (a code in which urls are hardcoded). In ASP.NET MVC applications you should always use HTML and Url helpers:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    Model.Name, 
    "Download", 
    "File", 
    new { id = Model.PkFileId }, 
    null
)
```

This way it is certain that no matter how your routes are configured or under which virtual directory your application is hosted, it should work.

---

UPDATE:

After your comment it looks like you are using the Telerik Grid. In this case you may try something along the lines to generate proper anchors:

```
columns
    .Bound(x => x.PkFileId)
    .ClientTemplate(
        Html.ActionLink(
            "<#= Name #>", 
            "Download", 
            "File", 
            new { id = "<#= PkFileId #>" }, 
            null
        ).ToString()
    )
    .Title("");
```

Comment: Haha, I knew I was going to get this... I'm using a dang Telerik Grid and couldn't seem to get it to like the ActionLink so we went down the wrong road apparently. I'll see if I can fix that...

Comment: Really!? `.ToString()`... Can't believe it was that simple. At first I had exactly what you posted, minus the `.ToString()`, obviously didn't work. Tried messing with qutoes... Then I tried `.Template(f => @Html.ActionLink(f.Name, "Download", "File", new { id = f.PkFileId }))` to no avail. Thanks for taking the time to help me with my real underlying problem.